# Google pay wont work unless phone is unlocked even for small payments

Tags: google-pay

I have a Samsung Note 9 (Android version 9) and Google Pay installed and configured. It works on stores like Costa for payments under £35 **only when phone is unlocked**

As per https://support.google.com/pay/answer/7644132?hl=en "No unlock needed for smaller payments"

Does anyone know why this is the case? I'd like that no unlocking is required for small payments.

Comment: Based on the linked help center, It seems the maximum limit for the United Kingdom is GBP 30?

Comment: Exactly! My point is that even for purchases below 30gbp I seem to have to unlock my phone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out this may be a problem with the official Samsung phone clear view folding cover explained in https://www.samsung.com/uk/smartphones/galaxy-note9/accessories/

When the fold is closed I cannot use it. If I open the fold then even if the phone is locked I can use Google Pay. Removing the foldable cover altogether also works!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if they've recently updated the support answer on your link or not but it's clear you can't always pay with a locked phone even for smaller payments.

> To make most purchases in stores, you need to unlock your phone. You won't need to unlock it for **certain** small payments.
>
> **Important: You can only make a limited amount of locked transactions before your phone will ask you to unlock it**.

Personally, I have to unlock my Pixel 3A even when the payment is as small as £2.